# Why is the output of my opamp mV?

Tags: operational-amplifier, sallen-key

I would like to use an Si514 as a tuneable oscillator driving later stages with 50 ohm impedance.  So I put an opamp on it and attempted to configure it as a saleen-key low pass filter (to round the squares).  The problem I have is, although it works, the output is 5mVpp if my cheap oscilloscope is to be believed.  My fluke multi-meter on DC says 1mV at J2 with no coax hooked up.

The first thing I know I did wrong is I accidentally swapped the + and - of my opamp when transcribing the circuit.  An online circuit simulator doesn't seem to care about this fact.  Nevertheless, is this the issue or is something else wrong?

[image: schematic]

Channel 1 is a coax cable attached at J2.  Channel 2 is a probe touching the oscillator side of R1.

[image]

Comment: The opamp has full POSITIVE feedback - swap the input nodes.

Comment: 1. As @LvW says, your inputs should be swapped.
2. Can you plot the input signal on Ch 2 so we can correlate it with the output?
3. Can you share a well-lit, detailed photo of your board + probing setup?

Comment: 1. Falstad Circuit Sim didn't show this as an issue but NI multisim seems to.  Is multisim right?  2. Added 3. I forgot nice test points so holding a probe on an 0805 part takes all of my attention much less taking a photo.